# React Native useEffect hook continues to be invoked even after component is unmounted

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native and I am trying to understand how the `useEffect` hook continues to work even after a component is unmounted.

I have the following screens defined in the stack navigator:

```js
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}></Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}></Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

I have the following code in `ChatScreen`:

```js
export default function ChatScreen({ navigation }: { navigation: any }) {
    const isError = useAppSelector((state) => state.chat.isError);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect')
        if (isError) {
            if (navigation.canGoBack())
            navigation.popToTop();
            return;
        }

        return () => { console.log('cleanup'); }
    }, [isError]);
}
```

`isError` comes from the redux store. When `isError` is true, it goes back to the Home screen because of the `navigation.popToTop()`. But, when `isError` is later modified in the store, I see that `useEffect` from `ChatScreen` is invoked again. Since `ChatScreen` is popped from the stack navigator, shouldn't the component be unmounted at this point? How does the `useEffect` still continue to be invoked?

I don't want the code inside `useEffect` to be executed when `isError` changes after `navigation.popToTop()` is done. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect')
        if (isError) {
            if (navigation.canGoBack())
            navigation.popToTop();
            return;
        }

        return () => { console.log('cleanup'); }
    }, [isError]); <-- try removing isError from the dependency array.

`

Comment: If I remove `isError` from the dependency array, it will not go back to home screen when `isError` is true. I want `useEffect` to not be executed any more after it has gone to the home screen. Any idea why it still executes after the app has gone back to home screen?

Comment: There is a workaround for your issue. You can add an extra condition along with isError flag. You must check if the screen is in focus. You can do it using [useIsFocused](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/).  You can find a sample of working code on this [link](https://snack.expo.dev/JmlVEeACR).